# Can epsilon-induction be derived from the transitive closure operator?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

I was wondering (and could not seem to prove or disprove) if epsilon-induction could be derived from the transitive closure operator for binary relations, if we do not have the Foundation Axiom.

The induction of the transitive closure operator is of the form:
If $R(x,y)\subseteq P(x,y)$ and P is a transitive relation, then $R^{+}(x,y)\subseteq P(x,y)$.

I have a hunch that this rule is strong enough to prove epsilon-induction even if we do not assume Foundation, but I may be wrong of course.(It is enought to prove the induction on N by itself). Perhaps some other weaker assumption is needed. 
I'd appreciate your help on this topic.

Comment: $\in$-induction is equivalent to Foundation; but the existence of transitive closures requires only some instance of Replacement, Infinity and Union.

Comment: You probably mean "Can we derive epsilon-induction" from **existence** of transitive closure operator, yes?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe one does not even need that much - what do you really need to be able to intersect all transitive relations containing $R$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: And there are such sets because?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $R\subseteq X^2$ for some set $X$, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Not necessarily. But also how does that ensure that you can find a *transitive set* containing $R$?

Comment: I thought it was about transitive relations, not sets. That is, any relations, not necessarily coinciding with membership. Is not this the case?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Oh, you're right. I didn't notice that. In this case probably separation and power set suffice.

Comment: I do mean transitive closure of relations, not of sets. The form of induction I stated for the transitive closure basically states that $R^{+}$ is the minimal transitive relation that contains $R$.I do not see however why seperation and powerset suffice in this case. Could you please elaborate some more? Many thanks!

Comment: @L.C. Once you can find any set $X$ which contains all $x$ and all $y$ satisfying $R(x,y)$, you just intersect all sets which are elements of the powerset of $X\times X$, which are transitive relations and which contain $R$.

Comment: On the afterthought - one may, if there is a wish, use union instead of separation: $\bigcup R$ may serve as one such $X$ (with the Kuratowski style ordered pairs, i. e. if $R(x,y)$ is taken to mean $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}\in R$).

Comment: You mean $\bigcup\bigcup R$.

Comment: It’s unclear if the question is about relations that are sets, or if $R$, $R^+$, $P$ are allowed to be proper classes. In the latter case, one can define $R^+(x,y)$ as “there exists $n\in\omega$ and a function $f\colon(n+1)\to V$ with $f(0)=x$, $f(n)=y$, and $R(f(i),f(i+1))$ for all $i<n$”. (I don’t need $\omega$ here to be a set.) The property in the question will require full induction on $\omega$ to prove, but that’s it, basically; it should go through with only extensionality, pairing, union, and separation. No foundation needed.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for the correction, yes, I (should) mean $\bigcup\bigcup$.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments, but I am afraid I still don't see how they answer my (intended) question. Perhaps I should be more accurate. Assume that for any given binary relation $R$ (or for every first-order formula with two variables for that matter), its transitive closure is available, denote it by $R^{+}$. A key property of $R^{+}$ is the one mentioned in my original post: If $R(x,y)\subseteq P(x,y)$ and P is transitive, then $R^{+}(x,y)\subseteq P(x,y)$. My question is, what (if any) other axioms are needed in order to prove epsilon induction? (If this is at all possible)

Comment: By epsilon induction I of course mean: $(\forall x(\forall y\in x.\psi(y)\rightarrow \psi(x)))\rightarrow\forall x \psi(x)$

Comment: The comments show that your property is provable in a weak fragment of set theory without epsilon induction, hence it is of no help whatsoever to prove epsilon induction. So the other axioms you need are epsilon induction itself, or foundation, or any other its equivalent formulation.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. Let $\newcommand\ZFC{\text{ZFC}}\ZFC^-$ be the theory $\ZFC$ without the foundation axiom. One can build models of $\ZFC^-$, which violate the foundation axioms, from any model of ZFC. For example, there are models of Aczel's [anti-foundation axiom AFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom), which satisfy $\ZFC^-$.

In any such model, $\in$-induction will fail, since the class of well-founded sets is inductive, but is not everything. But meanwhile, this theory proves that every set has a transitive closure, since for any set $X$, simply let $X_0=X$, $X_{n+1}=\cup X_n$, and let $Y=\bigcup_n X_n$. It follows easily that $Y$ is transitive and it is the smallest transitive set containing $X$. (This argument uses axiom of infinity, replacement and union as Asaf mentioned in the comments).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I do not however see (maybe this is obvious) how from this I get a refutation to the statement I mentioned.  I was referring to the transitive closure of binary relations.

Comment: Ah, sorry I had misunderstood. But the idea is similar for that case. As Emil explains in his comment, you can prove that every binary relation $R$ has a transitive closure, simply by saying $x$ is related to $y$, if there is a finite path from $x$ to $y$ through $R$. This new relation is transitive, and it is the smallest transitive relation containing $R$.